# Mac - how to open new links in a designated chrome window?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac

I have multiple chrome windows open, each with multiple tabs. I'd like to open links I click (e.g. in my mail client) in a specific chrome window each time. The default behavior seems almost random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links open on last active window. You can click the window you want first.

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to be true for me, I've just tried clicking the window where I want the link to be opened before clicking the link, but it ended up being open in the other window anyway.

Comment: @Bloke what application was the link in?

Comment: Slack! Do you think it could be a Slack issue?

Comment: For me this sometimes work and it opens links in the last active window. But then after rebooting or something it stops working. Super annoying. Would be cool to have a way to fix it, just restarting Chrome does not do the trick.